# Postgres - Trigger to erase all content of a table before an insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-10

I have a table with about 20k rows, and every day it gets another 20k rows.
It turns out that I will no longer need the 20k rows from the previous day. So I need to create a simple trigger to erase all table content before an insert.

I Tried:

```
--FUNCTION:
CREATE FUNCTION delete_old_rows_gmc() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM gmc;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;

--TRIGGER:
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_delete_old_rows_gmc
    BEFORE INSERT ON gmc
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_old_rows_gmc();
```

But after an insert, instead of bringing 20k rows, I have only 22 rows in the table.

Comment: Unrelated but don't do a DELETE, do a TRUNCATE - miles faster.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't insert all 20000 rows with a single `INSERT` statement, but with several. Now each of these triggers the trigger and deletes everything the previous `INSERT`s added, so you will end up with only the 22 rows from the last `INSERT`.

I don't think it is a good idea to do this with a trigger. Rather, explicitly run a

```
TRUNCATE gmc;
```

before you start loading.

Comment: Tried use truncate, got this message:

"message": "SQLSTATE[55006]: Object in use: 7 ERROR:  cannot TRUNCATE \"gmc\" because it is being used by active queries in this session\nCONTEXT:  SQL statement \"TRUNCATE gmc\"\nPL/pgSQL function delete_old_rows_gmc() line 3 at SQL statement"

Comment: Ah understand, but the procedure must happen even on days and times that will not have anyone to perform this function manually, so the need for a trigger.

The new rows come from an extraction tool, which loads the rows and inserts them into my database.

Comment: Don't do it manually. Build the `TRUNCATE` into whatever loads the data exported by the extraction tool.